# Header in php not working, insted shwos as echo, in other pages of the project works fine

Tags: php

I'm verifying login credentials in PHP, and if successful, I want to redirect to another page. Instead, it shows the code as an echo.

[image]

I tried:

```
header("Location: veiculos.html");
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>  window.location='veiculos.html'; </script>";
```

i used the `header("Location: veiculos.html");` in other pages and its working fine

what i have now:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $loginQuery = $conn->prepare("SELECT user, password FROM users WHERE user = ?");
    $loginQuery->bind_param("s", $username);
    $loginQuery->execute();
    $loginResult = $loginQuery->get_result();

    if ($loginResult->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = $loginResult->fetch_assoc();
        $storedPassword = $row["password"];

        if ($password === $storedPassword) {
         
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>  window.location='veiculos.html'; </script>";

        } else {
            echo "Invalid username or password.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid username or password.";
    }
    $loginQuery->close();}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Use _either_ PHP _or_ JS to redirect - no need for both (make sure to `exit` after a `header` in PHP). And _never_ store plain text passwords, PHP has [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)